# Changing a file automatically after creating a new branch

Tags: git, jira

I am using git (Jira is the remote) and I want to change a certain field in a specific file automatically right after I make a new branch and checkout for this new branch.

So for example, I have a file called "package.json" and there is a field called "version" inside. 
I want that right after I am creating a new branch (through Jira) called "abc123", checkout it locally, that I will see a change in that field and the value would be "abc123".
Is there any way to do this?
By the way, I prefer this will be implemented without creating a new commit automatically with this change. (though if it is the only way, I am fine with that :) )

thanks!

Comment: You can create a post-checkout hook. Since hooks are *programs* that *you* write, you can do literally anything you like in such a hook, including "detect that I checked out a different branch name, so write something into a work-tree file". A hook like this is per-repository so you must manually set it up in each clone, but once set up, it will stick around until you manually change or delete it.

Comment: That said, this sort of thing is usually a bad idea *unless* the file is *never checked in*. One reason for this is that any one commit can be on many different branches, and multiple branch names may select a single commit. Seriously, don't do this. Whatever your need for the current branch name is, satisfy that need by running `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` or `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD` at the point where it's needed, not by reading a file that was written long ago when the branch name was different.